# How to set custom attribute value in m2epro extension once order create in Magento admin Magento2

Tags: magento2, orders, custom-attributes, m2epro

I am using M2epro for Amazon and eBay. We want to set custom attribute value(static) once order creates in Magento admin. Can anyone have any idea how we can do it?

Comment: Can you please explain in brief....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to add a custom attribute in M2epro order.

Once the order has been placed in Magento using M2epro, it will trigger one event ess_order_place_success after order success in which you will get order object. 
You can create an observer using that event.

Below is the code for the event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="ess_order_place_success">
        <observer name="package_module_after" instance="PackageName\ModuleName\Observer\CreateOrderAfterObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and create an observer file name with CreateOrderAfterObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;

class CreateOrderAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        try {
                $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getMagentoOrder();
                // do what ever you want to do
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
             echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```